# How can I guarantee that a piece of code will only run if nothing goes wrong in python?

Tags: python, firebase, transactions, fastapi

I've thought about how to title the question correctly but I'm not sure I can accurately describe what I want. I will explain below.
I have an application in Python and FastAPI and in one functionality of the application I need to do things with two databases at the same time. For example, in the following code, I have a method that I use on an endpoint to delete a user and I need to delete the user from both my own database and the firebase database:

```
async def delete_db_firebase(self, *, _id: Union[int, str], route: Optional[str] = "") -> Any:
        """
        Method in charge of deletin user by uid in own database and in
        firebase.
        """
        url_database = f"{self.url}{route}/{_id}"
        url_firebase = f"{settings.AT_PRONOSTICOS_AUTH}/api/users/{_id}"
        response_database = await self._client.delete(url_service=url_database)
        await self._check_codes.check_codes(response=response_database, delete_method=True)
        response_firebase = await self._client.delete(url_service=url_firebase)
        await self._check_codes.check_codes(response=response_firebase, delete_method=True)
        return response_database
```

(self._client is simply a class that I created to handle the different HTTP requests in my application, I believe that for the context of the application it is not necessary to add it)
I then use my method in an endpoint:

```
@router.delete(
    "/{uid}",
    response_class=Response,
    status_code=204,
    responses={
        204: {"description": "User deleted"},
        401: {"description": "User unauthorized"},
    },
)
async def delete(
    *,
    uid: str,
    current_user=Security(get_current_user, scopes=["admin:user", "admin:guane"]),
) -> Response:
    """
    Delete user by uid send in the param.

    **Args**:
    - **id** (str, optional): the id of the register to delete.

    **Returns**:
    - **None**
    """
    await user_service.delete_db_firebase(_id=uid)
    return Response(status_code=204)
```

Perhaps you have already guessed my problem. In my code it is first deleted in my database and then in the firebase database. But one of the two could fail and I just want both deletions to be effective if neither fails. It would be like doing a "transaction" but I am in front of two different services. Is there any way to handle this in python?

Comment: Do the first deletion.  If it fails, you're done.  Do the second deletion.  If it fails, roll back the first deletion.  You can use a `try/except` to handle the flow control, but most of the work is probably going to be figuring out how to handle that rollback, rather than the logic around it.

Comment: It may be the only way. I doubt there is any way already built in to reverse the operation either in firebase or with my orm. Maybe I should just save a copy in my code and if something fails recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not possible to do a "transaction" between different services. That would have to be something that both services specifically choose to support between each other (and extremely unlikely to be the case, as transactions are already difficult to implement within a single service).

Without the ability to roll back or restore your first change, you will not be able to recover if the second change fails.  That's something you will almost certainly have to implement yourself.